# Microsoft App Registration - how to create meetings using OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All within an application context and not a user context?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, access-token, microsoft-graph-teams, azureportal

I currently have an app registration in Azure portal. This app has a client secret set up on it and a number of API Permissions as well. These are permissions for the Microsoft Graph and are delegated as well. This is how it looks like,
[image: Configured permissions]

Now I have also set up an App role for meetings as well, which looks like this,

[image: App roles]

With this context in mind, you can see I have added an application permission from the "My APIs" section, which points to my app registration and the permission for "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All". My objective is to obtain an access token in order for my client app to create a meeting whilst running the following POST,

POST /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/createOrGet

My question is to try and gain and understanding of what the authorization scope should be and the grant type as well when trying to obtain an access token. I have tried setting the authorization scope to be "offline_access [https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"](https://graph.microsoft.com/.default%22) and the grant type to be "client_credentials" but to no avail. I want my client app to be able to create a meeting on behalf of any user from my tenant without the need for user consent or any application access policies being needed to be set up in Powershell. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting up new App role, you need to add existing **Microsoft Graph** permission named *OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All* of **`Application`** type and grant consent to it.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permission** as below:

[image]

> Note that, you need to create **application access policy** and grant it access to `Global` to authorize the app configured in the policy to create **online meetings** on behalf of any user.

I used below PowerShell commands to install `MicrosoftTeams` module and create application access policy:

```
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -Force -AllowClobber

Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Sri-Test-policy -AppIds "xxxxxxxxxx" -Description "Allow access to Teams App"

Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName Sri-Test-policy -Global
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appID
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to make below POST request, **online meeting** created successfully like this:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/createOrGet
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "startDateTime":"2023-07-29T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2023-07-29T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"Sri Demo Online Meeting",
  "externalId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "participants": {
        "attendees": [
            {
                "identity": {
                    "user": {
                        "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    }
                },
                "upn": "demouser@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[onlineMeeting: createOrGet - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-createorget?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thank you sridevi for your answer although is there a way to do this without the need of setting up an application access policy in powershell? We wantt to create an app that our clients can make without the need for them to implement an access policy as well. Is this possible?

Comment: As mentioned in this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-createorget?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#:~:text=OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All*-,Important,-*%20Administrators%20must%20create), you must create application access policy if you are using `Application` permissions. There is no other way possible without it.

Comment: Will I need to create a new app registration to handle permissions with a "Delegated" type? It seems that my current app registration with combined appplication and delegated permissions does not allow my client application access for delegated permissions

Comment: Note that, **client credentials** flow works only with `Application` type permissions. If you want to use `Delegated` permissions, then you need to change your flow to interactive flows like authorization code flow. No need to create new application.

Comment: @Sridevi how do figure the value of userId in POST request? My Azure admin gave me the client_id/client_secret/tenant_id.

Comment: With client_id/client_secret/tenant_id, you can generate access token  only. `userId` in POST request refers to Object ID of user from which you want to create online meeting. You can get that Id like this: _Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Users -> All users -> Select user -> Find Object ID in Overview page_

Comment: @Sridevi Thank you. What would be externalId? Would that also be available in Azure?

Comment: @Sridevi My team is working on configuring this API to facilitate meeting creation, but we lack expertise in Azure and this api. Would you be open to assisting us with troubleshooting? I am willing to compensate you for your time. We've been grappling with this challenge for several months. Please reach out to me at ravimalghan at yahoo if you would be willing to help.